# how to update values into three tables in separate database?

Tags: php, mysql

The below code is on my localhost but not work in remote host, where first connection is work fine, following other DB connection not work. how to connect multiple mysql DB?

```
<?php
 $error=''; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$sno=$_POST['sno'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$item=$_POST['item'];
$name=$_POST['product'];    

include "connection/order_connection.php";  
$sql2="select item_code from warehouse_stock WHERE item_code='".$item."' and    sno!='".$sno."' ";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if($result2 === FALSE)
{    
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
if(mysql_fetch_array($result2)>= 1) 
{ 
echo  "Entered Item Code Already in Exists!<br/>";
echo '<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "list_products.php";
    }, 3500)
    }); 
    </script>'; 
}
else
{
// product insert into order and warehouse table
$sql1=("update warehouse_stock set date='".$date."',     product_name='".$name."', item_code='".$item."' where sno='".$sno."' ");
 $query1=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
 if($query1)
$sql2=("update order_stock set date='".$date."', product_name='".$name."',  item_code='".$item."' where sno='".$sno."' ");
$query2=mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);

// product insert into us hub table
include "connection/us_connection.php"; 
$sql3=("update stock_bal set date='".$date."', product_name='".$name."', item_code='".$item."' where sno='".$sno."' ");
$query3=mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);

// product insert into canada hub table
include "connection/canada_connection.php"; 
$sql4=("update stock_bal set date='".$date."', product_name='".$name."', item_code='".$item."' where sno='".$sno."' ");
$query4=mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
header('location:list_products.php');   
echo '<script>
$(window).load(function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.close();
}, 1500)
}); 
</script>';
//$error="Product details updated successfully!";

}
}
?>
```

Is there any other way to update values into table.?

Comment: You presented too much code. Please, narrow down your question. If the second connection doesn't work, it's the first thing for you to debug. Probably, the 2-nd database host is unreachable.

Comment: well first thing you should do is stop using **mysql_*** since that API is deprecated... you should switch to parametized queries with **mysqli_*** or **PDO**

Comment: Can we forget about all the (php) code for the time being? Let's just focus on the data base, and what you're trying to do there. If that's OK, amend your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm trying like this way for updating a single record, it work in my localhost, but not work in remote host. The code is same.

Comment: @karthik then the remote server is refusing a remote connection from your server. The issue is with the server that holds the MySQL databases. Check your MySQL logs (perhaps wrong password, perhaps user isn't set up with the new host, perhaps firewall issue?)

Comment: The same way to inserting record  and deleting records works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$error=''; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$sno=$_POST['sno'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$item=$_POST['item'];
$name=$_POST['product'];

// product insert into us hub table1    
$hostname="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_pwd="";
$dbname="jasmineus";

$con1 = mysql_connect($hostname,$db_user,$db_pwd);
if (!$con1)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname,$con1); 
$sql3=("update stock_bal set date='".$date."', product_name='".$name."', item_code='".$item."' where sno='".$sno."' ");
$query3=mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con1);

// product insert into canada hub table2
$hostname="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_pwd="";
$dbname="jasminecanada";

$con3 = mysql_connect($hostname,$db_user,$db_pwd);
if (!$con3)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname,$con3); 
$sql4=("update stock_bal set date='".$date."', product_name='".$name."', item_code='".$item."' where sno='".$sno."' ");
$query4=mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con3);

$yourURL="list_products.php";
echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
exit();
//$error="Product details updated successfully!";

}
$yourURL="list_products.php";
echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
exit();
die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```